# powershell invoke-command to variable and write out as a table

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have the following code, from what I would like to get the output to

> $output

and write-host at the end:

```
$outputs = @()
foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { 
    $output = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            invoke-command -computer comp3 -ScriptBlock { get-vm –VMName $using:comp | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | ft @{
            label="vm"; expression={$using:comp}}, 
            path,
            VhdType, 
            VhdFormat, 
            @{label="file(gb)"; expression={($_.FileSize / 1GB) -as [int]}}, 
            @{label="size(gb)"; expression={($_.Size / 1GB) -as [int]}} -AutoSize 
        }
    }
    $outputs += $output
}

$outputs
```

I get the error

> Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is coming from the `New-Object` cmdlet which is expecting a hash table be provided to the `-Property` parameter.

I don't think you need `New-Object` at all to get what I think you're after.

You might also want to consider using `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table` and then using `Format-Table` at the end to give you more flexibility over how you can further manipulate the results if needed.

You also can return the result of the `ForEach` directly rather than adding to an array, which is less efficient as the array is recreated each time:

```
$output = foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { 
    invoke-command -computer comp3 -ScriptBlock {
        get-vm –VMName $using:comp | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | Select-Object @{ label = "vm"; expression = {$using:comp} }, 
        path,
        VhdType, 
        VhdFormat, 
        @{label = "file(gb)"; expression = {($_.FileSize / 1GB) -as [int]} }, 
        @{label = "size(gb)"; expression = {($_.Size / 1GB) -as [int]} }
    }
}

$output | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: I'd like to point out using `New-Object PSObject`, `[pscustomobject]@{}` and calculated properties with `Select-Object` all result in the same thing.  The choice of one over another is a style choice (although you take a performance hit by using `New-Object`).

Comment: Agreed but format-object was definitely the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to your hashes, but the construct of the custom object looks pretty shaky. I would start with properly formatting the custom object with a Name/Value pair for each item you want in $outputs, and append $outputs directly with each iteration...

```
$outputs = @()

foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { 

    $outputs += [pscustomobject]@{

        Prop1 = Get-VM -Name $comp | Select -ExpandProperty Value1
        Prop2 = Get-VM -Name $comp | Select -ExpandProperty Value2
        Prop3 = Invoke-Commmand -ComputerName $comp -Scriptblock {Get-Something | Select Something}

    } 

}
```

Comment: You don't need to append a new object every iteration: just assign the output of the loop to a variable.  `$myvar = foreach (...`  It is *significantly* faster.